# XSLT transform for dynamic attribute allocation

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to convert xml to csv using java. I wrote a program to generate a csv file using xslt and it works with the following:

```
<xsl:text>PART_ID,TITLE,ITEM_NUMBER,SUBASSEMBLY_ITEM,QUANTITY</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
<xsl:for-each select="//row">
  <xsl:call-template name="CsvEscape"><xsl:with-param name="value" select="normalize-space(PART_ID)"/></xsl:call-template>
  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  <xsl:call-template name="CsvEscape"><xsl:with-param name="value" select="normalize-space(TITLE)"/></xsl:call-template>
  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  <xsl:call-template name="CsvEscape"><xsl:with-param name="value" select="normalize-space(ITEM_NUMBER)"/></xsl:call-template>
  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  <xsl:call-template name="CsvEscape"><xsl:with-param name="value" select="normalize-space(SUBASSEMBLY_ITEM)"/></xsl:call-template>
  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  <xsl:call-template name="CsvEscape"><xsl:with-param name="value" select="normalize-space(QUANTITY)"/></xsl:call-template>
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The table generated it properly formatted and any commas in my data are formatted properly in my CSV file using the CsvEscape function.

Now I am trying to make this dynamic so it works for any XML without me directly specifying the table headers.

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//row[1]">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <xsl:call-template name="CsvEscape"><xsl:with-param name="value" select="normalize-space(name(.))"/></xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="//row">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
                    <xsl:call-template name="CsvEscape"><xsl:with-param name="value" select="normalize-space(.)"/></xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

My XML:

```
<row>
    <PART_ID>15-00002-01</PART_ID>
    <TITLE>Shell Assembly</TITLE>
    <ITEM_NUMBER>4</ITEM_NUMBER>
    <SUBASSEMBLY_ITEM>18-00004-01 - Polyurethane, 4Ply, Hex Cut White Patches</SUBASSEMBLY_ITEM>
    <QUANTITY>15.000000000000</QUANTITY>
</row>
```

Note: Also items in the xml can have "," in them so i need to run it through CsvEscape for it to show up properly.

Required Output is:

```
    PART_ID,TITLE,ITEM_NUMBER,SUBASSEMBLY_ITEM,QUANTITY
15-20002-01,Shell Assembly,1,"18-20003-01 - Polyurethane, 4Ply, Hex Cut Black Patches",16.000000000000
```

This generated the CSV file with generating headers dynamically. The data is also being identified but it is not passing it through the CsvEscape function and this messes up my CSV file if there is a comma in my data.

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this input XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rows>
    <row>
        <cell>PART_ID</cell>
        <cell>TITLE</cell>
        <cell>ITEM_NUMBER</cell>
        <cell>SUBASSEMBLY_ITEM</cell>
        <cell>QUANTITY</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>id1</cell>
        <cell> some title </cell>
        <cell>1</cell>
        <cell>y;x,z</cell>
        <cell>20</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>id2</cell>
        <cell> another title </cell>
        <cell>2</cell>
        <cell>q/r|s</cell>
        <cell>10</cell>
    </row>
</rows>
```

here is a somewhat parametrised XPath-based solution to generically generate CSV output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="
            let $escapeChar := '&quot;',
                $newLine    := '&#xA;',
                $separator  := ','
                return //row ! (string-join(* ! string-join($escapeChar||normalize-space(.)||$escapeChar),$separator),$newLine)"
            separator=""/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
"PART_ID","TITLE","ITEM_NUMBER","SUBASSEMBLY_ITEM","QUANTITY" 
"id1","some title","1","y;x,z","20" 
"id2","another title","2","q/r|s","10"
```

If you want a more XSLT-based solution I'd recommend to make use of templates:

```xml
<xsl:variable name="escapeChar" select="'&quot;'" as="xs:string"/>
<xsl:variable name="separator" select="','" as="xs:string"/>
<xsl:variable name="newLine" select="'&#xA;'" as="xs:string"/>

<!-- identity template or shallow-skip -->
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

<xsl:template match="//row">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$newLine"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[parent::row]">
    <xsl:value-of select="$escapeChar"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$escapeChar"/>
    <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">
        <xsl:value-of select="$separator"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I will see if I can use it for mine. I updated my question with XML and the required output.